# Compare value of Dataframe column with list value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe columns 'id' and 'articles' and a list of values 'a_list' as below.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 4), (2, 3), (5, 6)], ("id", "articles"))

a_list = [1, 4, 6]
```

I am trying to compare list value with value of dataframe column "articles" and if match found updating column 'E' to 1 else 0

I am using "isin" in my code below

```
df['E'] = df.articles.isin(a_list).astype(int)
```

Getting

> TypeError: unexpected type: `<type 'type'>`

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide your type as string `"int"` instead of `int` which is python's native `type` that spark doesn't recognize; Also to create a column in spark data frame, use `withColumn` method instead of direct assignment:

```
df.withColumn('E', df.articles.isin(a_list).astype('int')).show()
+---+--------+---+
| id|articles|  E|
+---+--------+---+
|  1|       4|  1|
|  2|       3|  0|
|  5|       6|  1|
+---+--------+---+
```

Comment: Qq , so instead of updating column with int type , if i were to update it with a text , for 1= Confirmed and for 0 Not confirmed , is there way to do it within above solution ?

Comment: You can use `when.otherwise` to conditionally create a column. `import pyspark.sql.functions as f; df.withColumn('E', f.when(df.articles.isin(a_list), 'confirmed').otherwise('not confirmed'))`

Comment: Sorry to bother again ,if i have a mutiple list like  a_list=[4, 10] , b_list=[11,6] , c_list=[3,4] . How can i check against each list and if match found , update column "E" to "Found in a_list" (if found in a_list)  or  "Found in b_list" (if found in b_list)  or "Found in b_list" (if found in c_list)